# Remove parent and next-until Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure something like this:

```
  <div class="list_wrapper">  
    <div class="row mainrow">
    Main Row 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_remove_button">Remove</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="row subrow"> 
    Sub Row 
    </div> 
    <div class="row subrow"> 
    Sub Row 
    </div> 
    <div class="row mainrow">
    Main Row 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_remove_button">Remove</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="row subrow"> 
    Sub Row 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here, after `mainrow`, `subrow` can be inserted it is not mandatory. Now if I delete `mainrow` then its subsequent `subrow` should also be deleted, for that I'm trying this code but it is not working, current element which is `list_remove_button` on click deletes the closest `mainrow` but not the siblings `subrow` (of `mainrow`):

```
 $('.list_wrapper').on('click', '.list_remove_button', function()
    {
       $(this).closest('div.row').remove();
       $(this).children('.subrow').remove();
    });
```

Comment: `this` would be the `a` element which has no "children".

Comment: @Andreas: Current element is deleted but i want to delete subrow also that is just after deleted element

Comment: You question title is misleading. It's not a *"child"*, it's a *Parent next siblings - until*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Once you get the closest `.mainrow` using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- use [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)   to get the *next-siblings*
- and use [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addback/) to add back the initial `$main` to the stack - before `.remove()`*ing* them all

```js
$('.list_wrapper').on('click', '.list_remove_button', function() {
  const $main = $(this).closest('.mainrow');
  $main.nextUntil('.mainrow').addBack().remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="list_wrapper">
  <div class="row mainrow">
    Main Row 1
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_remove_button">Remove</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row subrow">
    Sub Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="row subrow">
    Sub Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="row mainrow">
    Main Row 2
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_remove_button">Remove</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row subrow">
    Sub Row 2
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```